# Perforce (p4) shelve workflow?

Tags: version-control, perforce, shelve

I'm trying to devise useful workflows for working with p4 shelve. I'm a git user and miss a lot of its features.

The basic flow (store an unfinished changelist, do something else, go back to finish the initial task – the equivalent of git stash) is trivial; I'm looking for tutorials/articles about how to use this feature in more complex scenarios.

Should I give up and use git-p4 or p4sandbox instead?

Answer (score 1):

There's one basic practice widely used in variety of tools - it's sharing changes among people.

1. Share as is - your pending change list will be accessible by others so they could take your delta to re-use
2. Share for review. E.g. Code Collaborator uses Perforce shelves as a subject to review.
3. Share for further automation. E.g. my company uses P4 pending changelists for taking changes into continuous integration with further submission in case of passing tests.

So basically from git or any other DVCS user point of view, shelves are a weird alternative to branches, there's nothing you can't do with shelves you can do with branches in DVCS.

Comment: I disagree with "there's nothing you can't do with shelves you can do with branches in DVCS". Currently I'm implementing a big feature. I've finished the first part, and shelved it (for backup and revision purposes). Now I'm implementing the second parft. If using git I would just commit the changes on top of the previous ones, but I can't see how to do it using p4 shelve: there's no connection between two different shelved changelists, I would have to create and maintain this connection manually (the equivalent of a local branch in git).

Comment: Shelving is very equivalent to 'git stash', although shelves are easier to share with others.  If you need a private branch you should use P4Sandbox or git with the git-p4 connector.  (Perforce is releasing a much improved git connector later this year.)

Comment: Yes, that's what I said in the question (shelving == git stash, probably I should use p4sandbox or git-p4).

Comment: That's what I'm talking about - branches are more generic than shelves. With branches you can do more that with shelves. In your case - yes, you'll have to connect those to shelved CLs manually.